# How to hide "WooCommerce" from menu for non admin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse28782_remove_menu_items' );
function remove_menus(){
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=shop_order' );       
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

How can I hide it?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the admin menu editor plugin which will let you modify your admin menu based on a users permissions.

https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/

Alternatively you can use a solution based on the users capabilities, this would target anyone that doesn't have admin privileges:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'no_woo' );

function no_woo() {
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') == false ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1: Modify code to achive this, (Universal Solution)**

You can use the following to debug:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wodebug_admin_menu' );

function wodebug_admin_menu() {

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

This gives (for my setup) the following for the Contact Form 7 plugin menu page:

```
[27] => Array
        (
            [0] => Formular
            [1] => wpcf7_read_contact_forms
            [2] => wpcf7
            [3] => Contact Form 7
            [4] => menu-top menu-icon-generic toplevel_page_wpcf7 menu-top-last
            [5] => toplevel_page_wpcf7
            [6] => none
        )
```

get the key and apply in your case.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages' );

function wpse_136058_remove_menu_pages() {

    remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=acf' );
    remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); // Key place in this
}
```

**Case 2: Use a Plugin.**

http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Answer (score -1):

This week I requested WooCommerce to change their setup, so this is better to manage. The idea needs votes, so please add your vote and hope we don't need to code such anymore: [https:ideas.woocommerce.com](https://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/39069922-woocommerce-should-not-reveal-an-overview-of-all-p). Please give it the maximum 3 points, thanks!

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all to the question being asked.